# How can I set recurrence to my events like google calendar?

Tags: mysql, reactjs, graphql, nestjs, typeorm

Good day people,

I am creating an app in nest.js in the backend,

I am trying to create a recurrent event but I don't grasp how can I do it correctly

this is my entity:

```
@Entity()
@ObjectType()
export class Event {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  @Field((type) => Int!)
  id!: number;

  @Column()
  @Field((type) => Int)
  userId: number;

  @Column()
  @Field()
  name!: string;

  @Column()
  @Field()
  eventStartDate!: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  eventEndDate?: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  color?: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  recurrenceRule?: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.event, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
  @Field((type) => User, { nullable: true })
  user?: User;
}
```

this is my create-event-input for graphql:

```
@InputType()
export class CreateEventInput {
  @Field()
  name!: string;

  @Field()
  eventStartDate!: Date;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  eventEndDate?: Date;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  recurrenceRule?: string;
}
```

And this is my create service:

```
create(createEventInput: CreateEventInput, userId) {
    const { recurrenceRule, ...rest } = createEventInput;
    if (recurrenceRule) {
      const rule = RRule.fromString(recurrenceRule);
      const eventDates = rule.all();
      const newEvents = eventDates.map((eventDate) =>
        this.eventsRepository.create({
          ...rest,
          userId,
          color: colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)],
          eventStartDate: eventDate,
          recurrenceRule: JSON.stringify(recurrenceRule),
        }),
      );
      return this.eventsRepository.save(newEvents);
    } else {
      const newEvent = this.eventsRepository.create({
        ...rest,
        userId,
        color: colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)],
      });
      return this.eventsRepository.save(newEvent);
    }
  }
```

The code I am sharing is basically what I tried

The thing is supposed to create only one master event that is going to be save in the db, and then save the repeated event with the RRule dependency and then if I give it the recurrenceRule, I could get those repeated events but with this code is only creating multiple events in the db

What is the correct way to do this